# multiple clicks registering in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a board that changes color upon a left mouse click.  But when I click it cycles through is_square_clicked() 3 times.  That's a problem, I only want it to do it once.  As you can probably guess this causes an issue for my program.  So how do I limit it to 1 pass through per click?  Thanks!

```
def is_square_clicked(mousepos):
    x, y = mousepos
    for i in xrange(ROWS):
        for j in xrange(COLS):
            for k in xrange(3):
                if x >= grid[i][j][1] and x <= grid[i][j][1] + BLOCK:
                    if y >= grid[i][j][2] and y <= grid[i][j][2] + BLOCK: 
                        if grid[i][j][0] == 0:
                            grid[i][j][0] = 1
                        elif grid[i][j][0] == 1:
                            grid[i][j][0] = 0

while __name__ == '__main__':
    tickFPS = Clock.tick(fps)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Press Esc to quit. FPS: %.2f" % (Clock.get_fps()))
    draw_grid()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
            mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            is_square_clicked(mousepos)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it cycles through is because you hold down the mouse long enough for it to check three times. I think if you have it wait between clicks, or you have it check not every time a cycle, it should be fixed.

Comment: I have it only activate on mousebuttonUP so holding the mouse won't be an issue, but what is the appropriate way to have it wait on a click? Does it make sense to pause the entire program while waiting on a click? Legitimate questions, not sarcasm.

Comment: @thefritobandit it depends on the program. What do you want this to do? if this is the only part of the program, yes it makes sense. Also, this could be seperate from the main program loop, so only this would pause.

Answer (score 0):

im going to guess that since the game loops more than once each click it changes more then once

even though a click is very fast the loop is looping faster (depending on the FPS)

here is an example that will change the color of the screen on each click:

```
"""Very basic.  Change the screen color with a mouse click."""
import os,sys  #used for sys.exit and os.environ
import pygame  #import the pygame module
from random import randint

class Control:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 0
    def update(self,Surf):
        self.event_loop()  #Run the event loop every frame
        Surf.fill(self.color) #Make updates to screen every frame
    def event_loop(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get(): #Check the events on the event queue
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                #If the user clicks the screen, change the color.
                self.color = [randint(0,255) for i in range(3)]
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit();sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'  #Center the screen.
    pygame.init() #Initialize Pygame
    Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500)) #Set the mode of the screen
    MyClock = pygame.time.Clock() #Create a clock to restrict framerate
    RunIt = Control()
    while 1:
        RunIt.update(Screen)
        pygame.display.update() #Update the screen
        MyClock.tick(60) #Restrict framerate
```

this code will blit a random color background each time you click so you can probably figure out the proper way to do it from the above code

Good Luck!